# Can't make nginx listen on nonstandard ports (3000, 35729)

Tags: nginx, web-server, port

This is on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 running on a VPS.

For example the following will work:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

When I visit the page it will be my `index.html`.

But if I try to make nginx listen on another port (35729):

```
server {
    listen 35729 default_server;
    root /var/www;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

or even one that's maybe slightly more used (3000 by nodejs servers for example)

All I get is an error saying the webpage is not available. [image].

Looking in netstat though says that nginx is listening for the port:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35729      0.0.0.0:*          LISTEN    15349/nginx -g daem
```

and iptables looks like this (which means no firewall right?)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and `sudo ufw status verbose` yields

```
Status: inactive
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you put port in url?

Comment: Yes I did in the form IP:35729

Comment: Check your firewall (both on the server and on the client side).

Comment: @EEAA I just enabled ufw...and somehow blocked off ssh...

Comment: Sounds like it's time to use that OOB management.

Comment: @EEAA I recovered the server and I'm back to where I started. It's a fresh Ubuntu install and I don't think it has any firewall configuration. Is there anything else that could be messing with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
# On Linux
sudo netstat -lntp 

# On FreeBSD
netstat -a | grep 'LISTEN'

# On Windows
netstat -bnp TCP -p TCPv6
```

and check  what port `nginx` listening

After changing configuration file don't forget

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

and check with `netstat` again, which port `nginx` listening now

If it's looks right, check your firewall, may be there poked only particular port on firewall.

Do `Ctrl+F5` in your browser  to refresh cache

P.S.
It would be much easier to spot a problem if you will provide your operation system next time you asking question

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it turned out that I had to open specific port in the customer panel of my server (Ubuntu 12.04) at the supplier's website.